# MapBasic - Select return 4 dig for Latitude/Longitude

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I have a table point (Lat/Long) 6 digits long; however, when I run SELECT the return values are 4 Digits long. How can I preserve 6 digits after running SELECT?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: If you could include a small sample of the data, that would be useful too

Answer (score 1):

The floating value is shown with only four digits. It does however contain more digits/decimals.

If you need to export the values, you can use the Format$() function to force more decimals:

```
Format$(LAT, "#.######")
```

where LAT is your column name.

The full SQL Select statement could look like this:

```
Select Format$(LAT, "#.######"), Format$(LONG, "#.######") From POINTS
```

Where LAT and LONG are your columns and POINTS is the name of your table.